# Why nested serializer in django not working in my code

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a nested serializer but code isn't working and I am unable to find out where the problem is.

Here are my models

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name=UniqueCharField("Name",)
    address=models.TextField("Address",blank=True,null=True,default='',)
    city=OptionalCharField("City Name",)
    state=OptionalCharField("State Name",)
    country=OptionalCharField("Country Name",)
    phoneno=OptionalCharField("Phone No.",)
    mobileno=OptionalCharField("Mobile No.",)
    emailid=OptionalCharField("Email Address",)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Company"
        verbose_name_plural="Companies"
        db_table="MST_Company"

class CompanyContacts(models.Model):
    companyname=models.ForeignKey(Company,models.CASCADE,"contactdetails")
    contactname=RequiredCharField("Contact Name",)
    contactno=OptionalCharField("Contact No.")
    emailid=OptionalCharField("Email ID")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Company Contact"
        verbose_name_plural="Company Contacts"
        db_table="MST_CompanyContacts"
```

and serializers,

```
class CompanyContactsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self,validated_data):
        return CompanyContacts.objects.create(**validated_data)     
    class Meta:
        model=CompanyContacts
        exclude=('companyname',)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contactdetails=CompanyContactsSerializer(required=False,many=True,read_only=False)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        contactdetails_data=validated_data.pop('contactdetails',None)
        mcompany=Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # company.save()
        if contactdetails_data:
            for contactdetail in contactdetails_data:
                CompanyContacts.objects.create(companyname=mcompany,**contactdetail)            
        return mcompany

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        extra_fields=['contactdetails']
        fields='__all__'
        read_only_fields=('date_created','date_modified','user_created','user_modified')
```

Here is my payload:

```
{
"id":"",
"name":"Test Company",
"address":"",
"city":"",
"state":"",
"country":"",
"phoneno":"",
"mobileno":"",
"emailid":"",
"contactdetails":[
{"contactname":"Test Name - 1","contactno":"Test Mobile - 1","emailid":"Test Email - 1"},
{"emailid":"Test Email - 2","contactno":"Test Mobile - 2","contactname":"Test Name - 2"}
]
}
```

Server response :

```
{
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

One thing I would like to bring into your notice is in the payload, If I omit contactdetails object, It gets saved successfully. Code is self explanatory, even then you require to ask anything, Please let me know and I will provide you the detailed explanation.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow guide
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

you should add in your `foreign key` `related name` and in your `serializer` in `class Meta` add your `related fields`

Comment: Thanks Yagnesh, That was a silly mistake not providing related_name, I corrected it and also added related field to class Meta of Company Serializer, But now I am getting 'Bad Request' as server response.

Comment: I think all of data in your class meta should be like the link, if you have server error its somethings mistake in your serializer

Comment: Hey Yagnesh, I cam across this post : https://www.erol.si/2015/09/django-rest-framework-nestedserializer-with-relation-and-crud/. 'name' field in Company model is set to be unique, Do you think it has something to do with my problem ?

Comment: If anybody interested to help, one more thing I would like to share with you is with the same payload desktop application works without any problem but getting bad request in web application, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself. It had nothing to do with the back-end, Actually, while sending POST request the team wasn't setting headers : {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"} and that lead server to respond with Bad Request. Hope someone else would benefit with this.

Thanks for each of you for taking some time to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should add in your `foreign key` `related name` and in your `serializer` in `class Meta`add your related fields